# The mailto link is not working when it is in react-bootstrap Dropdown component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The mail link will do nothing, not even an error message. I have this problem and the only work around is to right click and open it in a new tab. Then the default mail client of the machine will open up with correct values.

The same anchor component with the link will work if it is not in a Dropdown component.

Sample code snippet is as below.

```
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'

<Dropdown>
    <ul>
        <li> Some html component </li>
        <li> <a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">Send Email</a> </li>
    </ul>
</Dropdown>
```

Any idea how I can overcome this ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: The documentation seems to use the MenuItem component for links inside Dropdowns.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/